# Making up user audience?

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, design, user-research

I understand that, for someone who’s just starting to put together a portfolio without any “real” projects under his belt, made up projects and scenarios are acceptable pieces of work to include. Perhaps I should’ve asked this question before going forward with my current personal project, but while fabricating a portfolio-building project with made up problems and solutions, specs/requirements and features is supposed to be okay.

- Is it okay to also make up the results of the “pretend research” that
  was supposed to have gone behind it? I don’t mean reviewing
  analytics/stats/numbers.
- How about the more audience-engaging, interactive aspects of research
  like interviews and surveys?
- Stakeholder meetings?
- Do I make up the users based on my own educated guesses?
- Do I just look at the nature of the project and derive specs and
  requirements from these fictional users and stakeholders based on
  what I see as the current shortcomings/opportunities for improvement
  of the website or product?

My gut tells me it’s completely fine to do so, but I feel like it’s too easy to just conjure up scenarios and solutions. Is this okay?

Comment: I feel faking Stakeholder meetings, interviews, surveys will do more harm than good when you will be asked to explain your roleplay during portfolio presentation. Instead, I would suggest you assume specs and provide the WHY or Pros and Cons behind it.

Comment: @tridip1931 so funny that you posted that when you did! Was just reading another one of many articles about how ultimately the WHY and HOW trumps the WHAT in terms of the demonstration behind one’s work. But thank you for the response!

Comment: @tridip1931 would just like to make sure I’m understanding this correctly: whether this actually improves the product or website and wins the stakeholders’ praise isn’t as important (at least at this stage of my career) as clearly articulating the reasoning behind my approach TO and TOWARDS the solution. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it correct. Since you are just starting out, the recruiters will be more interested in how you articulate things and tooling skills (Sketch, Figma etc).

Comment: @tridip1931 very much appreciated 

Comment: @tridip1931 We rather give possible employees a small task and look at how they try to solve it. No matter if they can solve it or not, the way is more important for us to judge wether or not you know how to takle problem solving.

While I dislike made-up projects in Portfolios and most likely throw such applications in my bin (virtually), they can be very helpful for busy people to "judge" a possible employee.

Rather do real projects for free for gaming groups, communities or whatever. The size of the audience is not important, but to check if you had real world contact so far.

Comment: Perhaps find some friends to act as the stakeholders and others as users, then interview them.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need and SHOULDN'T do that.** The whole idea is that you **work with data** and the outcome of your work is **data driven**. If you make up numbers, your prospective employers may think *"so, what is this employee going to do for me? make up stuff?"* or simply don't care since you're not solving any real problem or doing any effort to get real data.

Now, **the thing is that you CAN get real data.** There's data anywhere, everywhere. Just get any public statistics on something and solve a problem related to those stats.

Remember you don't need to solve usability issues on every project, so it's OK if you don't perform usability testing. But even then, you can do have some colleagues or family or friends to help you as interviewees , or you can use remote tools like Hotjar or Google Analytics.

Also, you can offer an NGO to do some work *pro bono*, or help some friend with a site, or whatever. This will help you get more credibility with employers, you'll have "real life" experience and you'll probably get some recommendation letters or testimonials

Comment: Devin, thank you for that. The over analysis was starting to derail me. I look back and “oh... right.... of course.”

Answer (score 0):

The ability to test is also everywhere.  Usability is not just about websites and mobile apps.  It is about the world at large.  I would suggest people watching.  Go out and watch people and see where they stumble. When you start seeing what feels like something above the 20% of user population making the same kinds of errors start tracking, break the problem down with heuristic evaluation techniques. Then design a solution.  Present the solution to friends and family for candid feedback and capture that as design testing interviews / paper prototyping. Compile all the information and present that as a case study for your portfolio.